# Adding meeting in Outlook calendar

Tags: office-365, calendar, outlook

I want a feature where on click of a button a meeting is added to user's outlook calender.
I am using share point online so no managed code.
WHat is the easier way?

Answer (score 2):

At first you will need some information for the meeting: time, location,description etc. 
Where does this information comes from? Predefined or user related?

Another question would be: Where to place the button? At a page or within another form?

Without any information about my answers above I would suggest to check out Flow. It contains actions like create events in Outlook and it doesn´t require any coding skills. But Flow needs triggers to start the process. I suggest this could be the creation of an SharePoint list item where you can provide the information of the event.

The button could be a tile of the promoted links list, placed as web part on a page. The link of the tile would redirect to the new item form of the previously mentioned list. This would trigger the flow action and the event at outlook would be created.

Comment: There is event page that anyone can visit, which will say Add Event to my Calender. Time location Descp will come from sharepoint list. There will be button on sharepoint web part page that says Add to calendar that should add the event in the user's outlook calender. Your solution will be work if we create event and at same time add it. ANy idea how to solve issue of adding existing event.

Comment: Where does the existing event comes from? The mentioned SP list or in Outlook? Flow could be triggered by selecting the items of existing events of the SP list.

Comment: Events will be stored in SP List and a button on a sharepoint add that says "Add event to Calender". ON click of which it is expected to be added in Outlook.

Comment: If you create a Flow Workflow at the SharePoint list (only modern lists) you can select the list item and click on the flow button on top and then on the workflow name. This is the regular way to start the flow manually. If you want to start it with a big shiny button near the list you will have to do some more work. Then you have to create a new page and add a list view web part and a content Editor web part where the button is located. But how to do it exactly ist out of my knowledge space.